# EJS - Include return Could not find the include file "header.ejs"

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I try to render html with ejs like this

```
const ejs = require('ejs'),
      fs = require('fs'),
      str = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/../mail_templates/test.ejs`, 'utf8');

console.log(ejs.render(str, {name: 'abc'});
```

`test.ejs`

```
<%- include(`header.ejs`)%>
...
```

But got this error:

```
Error: ejs:1
>> 1| <%- include(`header.ejs`)%>

Could not find the include file "header.ejs"
...
```

Here is how the folder structure look like:

[image]

Can you tell me why? I also tried these cases but no hope:

```
<% include header.ejs %>
<% include header %>
<%- include('header.ejs'); -%>
<%- include('../mail_templates/header.ejs'); -%>
<%- include('mail_templates/header.ejs'); -%>
<%- include('./mail_templates/header.ejs'); -%>
```

The only case that work is to use the absolute path:

```
<%- include("/Users/admin/Work/engine/mail_templates/header.ejs")%>
```

But of course I don't want to use this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Includes are relative to current template. In order for the engine to be aware of current template path, it should be specified with `filename` option, something like:

```
const templatePath = `${__dirname}/../mail_templates/test.ejs`;
str = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, 'utf8');

ejs.render(str, {filename: templatePath, name: 'abc'});
```

Then it's expected that any of these includes will work:

```
<% include header.ejs %>
<% include header %>
<%- include('header.ejs'); -%>
<%- include('./header.ejs'); -%>
```

Comment: Thanks, saved my day! Though the it worked bit differently for me, filename is the key! I have added my code which worked for me since the options bit changed now

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks to @Estus Flask. Looking at his answer, I checked documentation and it worked for me. so adding the code here for reference.**

Now ejs.render accepts, check [EJS documentation](https://ejs.co/#docs)

```
ejs.render(str, data, options);
```

So, in my case below code worked

```
const templatePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../templates/parent.ejs');
const ejsTemplate = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, 'utf8');

const html = ejs.render(ejsTemplate, { data: data }, {filename : templatePath}); //I need to pass data. so used data object
```

As documentation says,

> ***filename Used by cache to key caches, and for includes***

In .ejs file I include partial templates as

```
<%- include('partials/child'); -%>
```