# EJS partials/components

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

If I have the following directory structure, is it possible to be able to render partials within partials, basically like creating a view setup that is not to dissimilar to react components (that's how I see it anyway)

```
- server
  - views
    - partials
      - components
          component-1.ejs
          component-2.ejs
      blog.ejs
      navbar.ejs
      footer.ejs
  home.ejs
  contact.ejs
```

So within my home page I have a partial `blog.ejs` and within that partial I would like to have `component-1.ejs`

I have tried a variety of permutations but am always faced with the error `Error: Could not find the include file`

home.ejs

```
<div class="example">
  <% include partials/blog %>
</div>
```

blog.ejs

```
<div class="another-example">
  <% include components/component-1 %>
</div>
```

Is this kind of rendering possible with EJS ?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874226/ejs-include-return-could-not-find-the-include-file-header-ejs

Comment: <%- include ('./partials/blog') %> this may help!!